# Avoid Constructor called from Tab key

Tags: c#, powershell, module, powershell-cmdlet

I'm writing a PowerShell module in C#. At runtime one of the cmdlets is called like this:

```bsh
Test-Path -Path \\path\to\somewhere
```

My constructor looks like this:

```cs
public TestPath()
{           
    checkPathExistence();           
}
```

This is working until the user at runtime presses the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key in order to autocomplete parameter name:

```
Test-Path -Pa <TAB>
```

The <kbd>Tab</kbd> key fires the constructor and this causes my `checkPathExistence()` method to give unwanted results. How can I make my `checkPathExistence()` wait for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key before checking anything?

My first idea was to check `Path` being null. But `Path` isn't mandatory. If the cmdlet is being called without any parameter some standard path from former sessions is being set.

```cs
void checkPathExistence()
{            
    if (!File.Exists(this.Path))
    {
       Path = Properties.Settings.Default.Path;
    }
    else
    {                
        Properties.Settings.Default.Path = Path;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        Console.WriteLine("The path has changed to: " + Path);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where TestPath's constructor is been called?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are calling `checkPathExistence` during the constructor.  Instead, it sounds like you only want to call it while processing the command-line including the path.  Leave the constructor empty, and instead handle the command-line during `ProcessRecord`. See [Cmdlet Input Processing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714463(v=vs.85).aspx).